# Directory of Debug.startMethodTracing() trace file

Tags: android, android-traceview

I'm trying to execute an app and calculate the startup time using the Debug.startMethodTracing() but I can't find the trace file. I've already added the `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>`. The problem is that I don't have an sd card so I don't know where android studio saves my file.

Any advice is much appreciated.

Thanks in advance,
Equinox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my problem. In the case your smartphone doesn't have an sdcard you should go to /storage/emulated/legacy (or similar path). There it is your trace file.

Answer (score 6):

Mine was here: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/[YOUR_PACKAGE]/files/dmtrace.trace

```
cd /storage/emulated/0
find -name *.trace
```

Answer (score 3):

In my case the trace file has been saved to location

```
/sdcard/Android/data/you.app.package.name/files/name.trace
```

Comment: That's also the location where I could find the file. I didn't have permission to see the content of `/storage/emulated/`

Comment: @AugustoCarmo You can use the "Device File Explorer" panel in Android Studio instead.

Answer (score 0):

In my case storage/emulated/0/android/data/your_package/files/... .strace